# Присвоение переменной значение строки

Tags: c#

Как в C# присвоить числовое значение переменной, записанное в строке?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019804/5698975

Answer (score 5):

Для конвертаций (преобразований) в .NET используются такие методы:

- `int` → `string`: `TryFormat`, `Format`, `ToString`
- `string` → `int`: `TryParse`, `Parse`

<sup>Примечание: Если имя метода выглядит как `TryXXX`, то он *всегда* возвращает `bool`: если ошибка, то `false`, иначе `true`.</sup>

Таким образом остаётся такой набор методов: `Format`, `ToString`, `Parse` (прочие методы рассматриваться не будут). Разберёмся с каждым по порядку.

- `Format`: записывает `int` → `Span<char>` в виде строки. `Span` – это универсальный буфер: в нём можно хранить строку, массив и даже неуправляемый буфер. `Span` – это всего лишь ссылка на элемент исходного буфера + длина, т. е.

```
var span = str.AsSpan();
```

…*не создаёт новый буфер*. Поэтому но так важен. [Ссылка #1](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/420051/), [cсылка #2](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/418911/), если вы хотите подробнее узнать о `Span`.

- `ToString` просто преобразует `int` → `string` (возможно, вам когда-то давали задание: «Преобразуйте беззнаковое целочисленное число в строку»).
- `Parse` делает обратное, т. е. `string`/`ReadOnlySpan<char>` → `int`. Это то, что вам нужно.

---

Также методы `Format` и `ToString` имеют 2 аргумента: `format` и `formatProvider`. `format` – это, как не сложно догадаться, [формат числа](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), т. е. нужно ли ставить пробелы м-ду каждыми 3-я цифрами, нужно ли указывать валюту, или это процент, и т. д. `formatProvider` – это поставщик форматера. Это сложно, поэтому просто знайте, что в него можно запихнуть нужную [культуру](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/28.1.php). Например:

```
var num = 5;
var ruRU = new CultureInfo("ru-RU"); // русская культура
var enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // американская культура

Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("C", ruRU)); // 5,00 ₽
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("C", enUS)); // $5.00
```

---

Метод `Parse` также принимает 2 аргумента: `style` и `formatProvider`. Про 2-й вы уже знаете – повторяться не буду. Аргумент `style` указывает допущения для числа, т. е. может ли оно иметь те же пробелы, может ли оно быть 16-ричным, может ли иметь минус и т. д. Т. е. полная противоположность `format`.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте `Int32.Parse(string)` и обратно `number.ToString()`