# Является ли строка числом в вводе в C#

Tags: c#, строки

Мне нужно написать проверку на C#. Проверка заключается в следующем, как проверить ввод пользователя и понять это строка является числом или строкой. Например мне надо, чтобы пользователь заполнил массив и если он вводит не целое число, то программа будет выдавать "Введите число". Есть идеи, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Ибо я только начинаю изучать C# любой совет мне очень полезен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144663/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8/1144681#1144681 – мой ответ на подобный вопрос (не дубликат)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто дополню комментарии примером

```csharp
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Введите число: ");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(text, out int number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели число {0}", number);
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Не удалось распознать число, попробуйте еще раз.");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 2):

Есть метод для char - IsDigit

```
bool StringIsDigits(string s)
{
   foreach(var item in s)
   {
      if(!char.IsDigit(item))
         return false; //если хоть один символ не число, то выкидываешь "ложь"
   }
   return true; //если ни разу не выбило в цикле, значит, все символы - это цифры
}
```